# Aplicação React Native utilizando Firebase

Tags: firebase, react, react-native

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação utilizando React Native, e tentando integrar com Firebase, encontrei uma aplicação de starter project, do qual já conta com a integração pronta, precisando somente adicionar o `google-services.json` ao diretório raiz da aplicação android, `android/app`, segui todos os passos do qual são descritos no Readme do repositório que se encontra na seguinte URL:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter

Dito isso, e feito todos os passos descritos para iniciar o projeto, realizei a entrada do seguinte comando no console, para que o projeto iniciado: `npm run android`, do qual me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
   > Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Parsing json file: C:\Development\react-native-firebase-starter\android\app\google-services.json


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.unisul.testcar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
16 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 15 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar o Firebase desta maneira:

1. Vá até http://firebase.google.com/
2. Vá no Console e crie um novo projeto
3. Após criado o projeto, escolha para adicionar "Autenticação" por exemplo. Em "Método de login", escolha "Email/Senha" ou qualquer outro de sua escolha
4. Feito isso, no canto superior direito, vá em "Configuração da Web" para pegar suas credenciais e cole isto em seu App.js, por exemplo:

   ```
   class App extends Component {
       componentWillMount() {
       const firebase = require('firebase');

       const config = {
         apiKey: 'xxxx',
         authDomain: 'xxxx',
         databaseURL: 'xxxx',
         projectId: 'xxxx',
         storageBucket: 'xxxx',
         messagingSenderId: 'xxxx'
       };
       firebase.initializeApp(config);
   }
   ```

Instale a depêndencia do Firebase no seu projeto utilizando npm:

```
    npm install --save firebase
```

Teste e veja se funciona.

Comment: Funcionou como o esperado!! Muito obrigado!